# установка sfml под atom

Tags: c++, sfml, atom

Просьба подсказать как работать с sfml под atom:

- Есть ли какое руководство в виде ссылки?
- Скажем под VS ставится элементарно, понятно, что atom это не IDE, поэтому с какой стороны зайти ?

Comment: точно также, как и с sfml под vim, emacs или vscode. Разницы никакой

Comment: @KoVadim проблема в том , что нет понимания как там устроен процесс компиляции в этих редакторах. Верно ли я понимаю , что там просто идет запуск gcc (g++)  ?

Comment: там будет запуск того, что Вы пропишите. Можно просто g++, а можно использовать cmake/makefile. То есть, разбейте свою задачу на две - первая, как собрать в консоли sfml проект через make/cmake, второе, как использовать cmake/make их под atom.